# CreateJS: Collision implementing problems

Tags: javascript, collision, easeljs, createjs, sliding

So I have this little javascript labyrinth game I've been working on. The player controls a character using the mouse cursor.
I have a semi-transparent .png bitmap for walls (all in one file), and the player.

The problem here is that I can't seem to make a working collision system.

Here's the essential part of the code:

```
// Calculate the distances between the cursor and the player
var xDistance = stage.getStage().mouseX - player.x;
var yDistance = stage.getStage().mouseY - player.y;

// Move the player
if (distance > 1) {
    player.x += xDistance * easingAmount;
    player.y += yDistance * easingAmount;
}

// Check collision for player (bounds)
var mapCollision = collisionMethod(bounds, mapLines, 1);
if (mapCollision) {
    if (xDistance > 0 || xDistance < 0)
        player.x -= xDistance * easingAmount;

    else if (yDistance > 0 || yDistance < 0)
        player.y -= yDistance * easingAmount;
}
```

CollisionMethod is actually ndgmr.checkPixelCollision.

The collision should slide along the walls. This collision only works when the player collides with Y-axis walls.

I am still pretty new with JS, and there's probably a better way to create collision for this kind of situation, so any kind of help or information would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure since I don't know most of your code but try not to use else if but instead use only if.  Also you can shorten  if (xDistance > 0 || xDistance < 0) to  if (xDistance) or just don't use if at all, if it's 0 then u substract 0.

Comment: why are you calling `getStage` on the stage? If `stage` is an EaselJS stage instance, then it will just return a reference to itself.

Comment: Thanks for the good points. Here's a simple demo of the specific problem [link](http://hypergaem.droppages.com/) and here's the actual JS code for that [link](http://hypergaem.droppages.com/Data/Games/labyrinth.js). I removed the else from the if statement (line 128) but now the player gets stuck when touching a wall.